# Is CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat different on OS and .NET version?

Tags: .net, datetime

I ran the following code on two different PC's

```
string info = string.Format("CLR Ver. {0}, Culture Name: {1},  ShortDatePattern: {2}", Environment.Version, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 with .NET 3.5, this is the value of `info`

> CLR Ver. 2.0.50727.5485, Culture Name: English (Canada), 
>   ShortDatePattern: dd/MM/yyyy

However, on a Windows Server 2012 with .NET 4.5, the value is

> CLR Ver. 4.0.30319.34209, Culture Name: English (Canada), 
>   ShortDatePattern: yyyy-MM-dd

I am wondering why CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat is dependent on .NET version?? Is this a breaking change in .NET4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the default short-date format for `en-CA` was changed, as of .NET 4.0.  You can test this yourself:

```
Console.WriteLine(new CultureInfo("en-CA").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Running on .NET 2 runtime (framework 2.0/3.x) will give `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.  Running on .NET 4 runtime (framework 4.x) will give `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

This is described in the MSDN document: [What's New in Globalization and Localization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997383.aspx#updated_globalization_property_values).  A few cultures are listed in an example table, but there are many others that were also updated, including `en-CA`.

Also you might want to check the date/time settings in the windows control panel.  It's possible that one of the machine's settings has been customized.  This will carry through to the current culture's format settings.

Also, date/time format changes would come through `CurrentCulture`. The `CurrentUICulture` is for resource string lookup via .resx files.

Comment: Yes I did that on the Windows Server 2012 box - I changed Date format to "dd-MM-yyyy". I even restarted the site and AppPool...still getting ShortDatePattern: yyyy-MM-dd